# VBA Excel run-time error 4198 command failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have problem with code below. On my PC itruns OK and generate PDF file from Word templates. I tried .rtf or .docx format of template doc. On PC at work I got

> runtime error 4198 command failed.

On another PC (notebook) same error. On all PC's I have installed Word and Excel.

```
Sub PdfEleDomVtNt()
    Dim wdDoc As Document
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Dim objField1 As Object
    Dim objField2 As Object
    Dim objField3 As Object
    Dim objField4 As Object
    Dim objField5 As Object
    Dim objField6 As Object
    Dim objField7 As Object
    Dim objField8 As Object
    Dim objField9 As Object
    Dim objField10 As Object
    Dim objField11 As Object
    Dim objField12 As Object
    Dim objField13 As Object
    Dim objField14 As Object
    Dim objField15 As Object
    Dim objField16 As Object
    Dim objField17 As Object
    Dim objField18 As Object
    Dim objField19 As Object
    Dim objField20 As Object
    Dim objField21 As Object
    Dim objField22 As Object
    Dim objField23 As Object
    Dim objField24 As Object
    Dim objField25 As Object
    Dim objField26 As Object
    Dim objField27 As Object
    Dim objField28 As Object
    Dim objField29 As Object
    Dim objField30 As Object
    Dim objField31 As Object
    Dim objField32 As Object
    Dim objField33 As Object
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("B21").Dirty
    
    Dim pdfFileName As Variant
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("A20").Value = "" Then
    pdfFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" + Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("B23").Value + ".pdf"
    Else
    
    pdfFileName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("A20").Value + "\" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("B23").Value + ".pdf"
    End If
    
    wdApp.Visible = False 'Nastav hodtnotu Tru pro viditelnost aplikace Word
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\YELLO_Kalkulace_MOO_2T_ELE.rtf") 
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set objField1 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text1")
    Set objField2 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text2")
    Set objField3 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text3")
    Set objField4 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text4")
    Set objField5 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text5")
    Set objField6 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text6")
    Set objField7 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text7")
    Set objField8 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text8")
    Set objField9 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text9")
    Set objField10 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text10")
    Set objField11 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text11")
    Set objField12 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text12")
    Set objField13 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text13")
    Set objField14 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text14")
    Set objField15 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text15")
    Set objField16 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text16")
    Set objField17 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text17")
    Set objField18 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text18")
    Set objField19 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text19")
    Set objField20 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text20")
    Set objField21 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text21")
    Set objField22 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text22")
    Set objField23 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text23")
    Set objField24 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text24")
    Set objField25 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text25")
    Set objField26 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text26")
    Set objField27 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text27")
    Set objField28 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text28")
    Set objField29 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text29")
    Set objField30 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text30")
    Set objField31 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text31")
    Set objField32 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text32")
    Set objField33 = wdDoc.FormFields("Text33")
    
    objField1.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N3"), "# ###")
    objField2.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N4")
    objField3.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N5")
    objField4.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N6")
    objField5.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N7")
    objField6.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N8")
    objField7.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N9")
    objField8.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N10")
    objField9.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N11")
    objField10.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N12"), "### ###")
    objField11.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N13"), "### ###")
    objField12.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N14"), "# ###,##0.00") 
    objField13.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N15"), "# ###,##0.00") 
    objField14.Result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N16") 'frekvence
    objField15.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N17"), "### ###") 
    objField16.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N18"), "#,###0.000") 
    objField17.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N19"), "#,###0.000") 
    objField18.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N20"), "#,###0.000") 
    objField19.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N21"), "#,###0.000") 
    objField20.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N22"), "# ###,##0.00") 
    objField21.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N23"), "# ###,##0.00") 
    objField22.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N24"), "#,###0.000")
    objField23.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N25"), "#,###0.000")
    objField24.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N26"), "#,###0.000")
    objField25.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N27"), "#,###0.000")
    objField26.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N28"), "# ###,##0.00")
    objField27.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N29"), "# ###,##0.00")
    objField28.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N30"), "#,###0.000")
    objField29.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N31"), "#,###0.000")
    objField30.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N32"), "#,###0.000")
    objField31.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N33"), "#,###0.000")
    objField32.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N34"), "# ###,##0.00")
    objField33.Result = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty").Range("N35"), "# ###,##0.00")
    
    wdDoc.SaveAs pdfFileName, wdFormatPDF
    
    objField1.Result = ("")
    objField2.Result = ("")
    objField3.Result = ("")
    objField4.Result = ("")
    objField5.Result = ("")
    objField6.Result = ("")
    objField7.Result = ("")
    objField8.Result = ("")
    objField9.Result = ("")
    objField10.Result = ("")
    objField11.Result = ("")
    objField12.Result = ("")
    objField13.Result = ("")
    objField14.Result = ("")
    objField15.Result = ("")
    objField16.Result = ("")
    objField17.Result = ("")
    objField18.Result = ("")
    objField19.Result = ("")
    objField20.Result = ("")
    objField21.Result = ("")
    objField22.Result = ("")
    objField23.Result = ("")
    objField24.Result = ("")
    objField25.Result = ("")
    objField26.Result = ("")
    objField27.Result = ("")
    objField28.Result = ("")
    objField29.Result = ("")
    objField30.Result = ("")
    objField31.Result = ("")
    objField32.Result = ("")
    objField33.Result = ("")
    
    wdDoc.Close
    wdApp.Quit
    
    Shell "rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " & pdfFileName, vbNormalFocus
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Soubor se šablonou se nepodařilo otevřít. Zkontrolujte cestu a název souboru.", vbCritical
End Sub
```

I checked references in VBA, changing doc type of template but I am at the end. I also try google runtime error 4198 but nothing what help me. Error shows up on line with code "wdDoc.SaveAs pdfFileName, wdFormatPDF" but as I said only on work PC or notebook.

Comment: Please indicate the line(s) that cause the error.

Comment: Hi sorry here error occurs wdDoc.SaveAs pdfFileName, wdFormatPDF

Comment: And what is the exact value of `pdfFileName` when you get the error? If it is correct, does that exact path exist on all computers running it?

Comment: brax thanks I will try - now i change the value of pdfFileName and works well on my PC, now I try on work PC and post feedback

Comment: You should also read up on how to use arrays/collections.  It will help to simplify your code.

Comment: You should also be aware the to concatenate strings you should use the '&' symbol.  Using '+' is a by product of VBA type cooercion which can lead to problems when variables you think are strings are coerced to numbers..

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the same object to fill the form fields.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PdfEleDomVtNt()

    Const TEMPLATE = "YELLO_Kalkulace_MOO_2T_ELE.rtf"

    Dim wdDoc As Document, wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, folder As String
    Dim objField As Word.FormField, v As Variant
    Dim pdfFileName As String, i As Long
      
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("vlozene_hodnoty")
    
    With ws
        .Range("B21").Dirty
        If .Range("A20").Value = "" Then
            folder = wb.Path
        Else
            folder = .Range("A20").Value
        End If
        If Right(folder, 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"
        pdfFileName = folder & .Range("B23").Value + ".pdf"
    End With
    
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    wdApp.Visible = False 'Nastav hodtnotu Tru pro viditelnost aplikace Word
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wb.Path & "\Templates\" & TEMPLATE)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For i = 3 To 35
        v = ws.Cells(i, "N")
        Set objField = wdDoc.FormFields("Text" & i - 2)
        Select Case i
            Case 3
               objField.result = Format(v, "# ###")
               
            Case 4 To 11, 16 'frekvence
                objField.result = v
                
            Case 12, 13, 17
                objField.result = Format(v, "### ###")
                
            Case 14, 15, 22, 23, 28, 29, 34, 35
                objField.result = Format(v, "# ###,##0.00")
                
            Case Else
                objField.result = Format(v, "#,###0.000")
        End Select
    Next
 
    Debug.Print pdfFileName
    wdDoc.SaveAs pdfFileName, wdFormatPDF
    wdDoc.Close
    wdApp.Quit
    
    MsgBox pdfFileName & " Created", vbInformation
    
    Shell "rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " & pdfFileName, vbNormalFocus
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Soubor se šablonou se nepodarilo otevrít. Zkontrolujte cestu a název souboru.", vbCritical
End Sub
```